# Using requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I ran across an issue where my code worked just fine in Chrome but in Safari it began to stutter. I read somewhere that "Safari caps intervals at 1000ms and then adds its own exponential delay, doubling every iteration." That being said I am trying to change my code to work both on Safari and Chrome using requestAnimationFrame but am having issues wrapping my head around the subject.

Essentially what I am trying to do is ease a div across a page with each click using requestAnimationFrame instead of setInterval.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is the Javascript:

```
let progressAvatar = document.querySelector('.box');
progressAvatar.addEventListener('click', checkClick);


var clicks = 0;

function checkClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  if (clicks == 1) {
    startingLocationOfAvatar();
  } else if (clicks == 2) {
    locationOfAvatar();
  }
}


function startingLocationOfAvatar() {
   let speed = 10;
  // Initial location of Avatar
  let pos = 0;
  // Ending location of Avatar
  let progressBarWidthDivided = 53;
  let id = setInterval(frame, speed);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == progressBarWidthDivided) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      progressAvatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}


// Move the avatar based on its previous location
function locationOfAvatar() {
  let speed = 10;
  // Pos becomes last location of movePixels
  let pos = 53;
  let id = setInterval(frame, speed);

  // movePixels adds last location by its new location
  let movePixels = pos * 2;

  function frame() {
    if (pos == movePixels) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      progressAvatar.style.marginLeft = pos + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Html:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here is the Css:

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Lastly here is a jsfiddle:
[Move Div Across Screen](https://jsfiddle.net/oun04Ltp/26/)

Comment: At the moment I am not using RAF. I am trying to refract the code to not use setInterval and instead use RAF.

Comment: yes, and the statement is that the fiddle link I posted is your code using RAF ... it's not a question (sorry, I just saw how that could be misinterpreted let me delete and repost the comment)

Comment: Here is your code changed to use RAF - https://jsfiddle.net/0py9dg8s/

Comment: Thank you, what is the logic behind the speed that the box moves across the screen?

Comment: Raf speed  is 60fps.  So 16.66ms

Answer (score 1):

I will let experts answer, but as a 2 weeks coding noob this is what i know,  you can compile all individual animation functions into a grand Animation function. And call that function with request animation frame. Trying to make a sensible game myself, i have totally given up on manipulating css values and coding in pure Javascript.

Note, dependent where you will put your mini-functions  - the photos/graphical items will display either on top or under eachother visually.

It should look something like this:

```
function drawEverything(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    context.save();
    draw();
    draw1();
    draw2();
    context.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
}
requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
```

Comment: I fixed your code layout - I also changed the last line to `requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);` so that every call to `drawEverything` is done on a "animation frame"

Comment: Thank you. I call RAF inside the function and the function itself outside. Works either way, many thanks. Good to know.

Comment: I understand, but if your first call to `drawEverything` does not use RAF, then the first animation frame would be done out of sync with respect to the rest of the animation :p